# What's matter with my Socket-based EchoServer and EchoClient?

Tags: java, sockets, scala

I wrote a Socket-based EchoServer and EchoClient:

```
package socket.echo

import actors.Actor
import java.net.{InetSocketAddress, Socket, ServerSocket}
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, InputStream, OutputStream}

object EchoServer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val port = if (args.length > 1 && args(0) != null) args(0).toInt else 8080;
    val backlog = if (args.length > 2 && args(1) != null) args(1).toInt else 50;
    new EchoServer(port, backlog).start()
  }
}

class EchoServer(val port: Int, val backlog: Int) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, backlog)
    println("Create a serverSocket: " + serverSocket)
    var isStop = false
    while (!isStop) {
      val socket = serverSocket.accept();
      println("Create a socket " + socket)
      Actor.actor {
        val is = socket.getInputStream
        val os = socket.getOutputStream
        val buf = IO.read(is)
        os.write(buf)
        os.flush()
        is.close()
        os.close()
        val msg = new String(buf, "UTF-8")
        println("Receive " + msg + " from " + socket)
        if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(msg)) isStop = true
        socket.close()
      }
    }
    println("Server stop! ")
  }
}

object IO {
  val BYTE_BLOCK_LENGTH = 1024
  /**
   * The input and output stream won't be closed after the method invocation
   *
   * @param is
   * @param os
   */
  def copy(is: InputStream, os: OutputStream): Unit = {
    var buf = new Array[Byte](BYTE_BLOCK_LENGTH)
    var isStop = false
    while (!isStop) {
      val len = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
      if (len == -1) isStop = true
      else os.write(buf, 0, len)
    }
  }

  def read(is: InputStream, encoding: String): String = {
    var resBytes: Array[Byte] = read(is)
    return new String(resBytes, encoding)
  }

  def read(is: InputStream): Array[Byte] = {
    var baos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BYTE_BLOCK_LENGTH)
    copy(is, baos)
    baos.flush
    var resBytes: Array[Byte] = baos.toByteArray
    is.close
    baos.close
    return resBytes
  }
}

object EchoClient {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ip = if (args.length > 1 && args(0) != null) args(0) else "127.0.0.1";
    val port = if (args.length > 2 && args(1) != null) args(1).toInt else 8080
    val n = if (args.length > 3 && args(2) != null) args(2).toInt else 100
    val isReuseAddr = if (args.length > 4 && args(3) != null) args(3).toBoolean else false

    for (i <- 0 until n) {
      val socket = createSocket(ip, port, isReuseAddr)
      val msg = "hello"
      println("send " + msg + " to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress)
      val is = socket.getInputStream()
      val os = socket.getOutputStream()
      os.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"))
      os.flush()
      IO.read(is)
      is.close
      os.close
      socket.close
    }


  }

  private def createSocket(ip: String, port: Int, isReuseAddr: Boolean): Socket = {
    val socket = new Socket()
    socket.setReuseAddress(isReuseAddr)
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port))
    return socket;
  }
}
```

When EchoClient was launched after the EchoServer started , EchoServer is blocked on `IO.read(is)`， for if i close the EchoClient, the EchoServer complain:

```
scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1@1dd46f7: caught java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at socket.echo.IO$.copy(Echo.scala:61)
    at socket.echo.IO$.read(Echo.scala:74)
    at socket.echo.EchoServer$$anonfun$act$1.apply$mcV$sp(Echo.scala:34)
    at scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1.act(Actor.scala:133)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:222)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:222)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$AdaptedRunnable.exec(ForkJoinPool.java:611)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
```

Is there any thing wrong in my code ?

PS: The sample code is written in Scala, but I think it is easy to understand by Java programmers

Comment: I don't know scala but here's a couple things to try.  Try making the read buffer a lot smaller to see if you are getting any bytes of the message.  Another thing to try is to close the socket in the client after your write the message.  It may be that `flush` is not actually flushing data out the socket.  Can you use some sort of proxy connection to see if it works?  How about `tcpdump`?  Can you telnet to the server and type in a bunch of stuff to see if it gets it?

Comment: I cqannot find this so simple to filter a bug!

Answer (score 0):

As your client is blocking reading the echoed reply, the main question is whether your server is really echoing everything you are reading. Your I/O code is excessively complicated for this simple task. There is no need for ByteArrayOutputStreams, or conversion to Strings, etc. Just read and write bytes, making sure to only write the number of bytes you read. 'Connection reset' usually means you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end.